# Windows Shell Extension using Managed Code

Tags: shell-extensions, clr4.0

basically every SO thread concerning Windows Shell Extensions (to e.g. display overlay icons or extend the explorer context menu for specific files) heavily advises against using managed code for this purpose.
I perfectly understand the reasoning given at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

My question is if these words of caution still hold truth when operating within CLR4.0 environments. 
As far as I understood http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/CLR-4-Side-by-Side-In-Process-What-How-Why loading managed code relying on different CLR versions into the same process (in this case explorer.exe) is handled more gracefully in CLR4.0.

Thank you a lot for your insight here.

Comment: Here is another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732475/in-proc-sxs-opens-for-shell-extension-in-managed-code